# JSON Cookie problem

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using [CookieJar](http://www.lalit.org/lab/jsoncookies) to read and write an Array of Objects to a cookie.

In my ClickButton function I do read the existing cookie and add to the Array of objects before I over write it again.

Here are the JSON string being saved:

```
[{"id":"3","value":"33333","text":"Bbbbb"},
 [{"id":"3","value":"33333","text":"Bbbbb"},
  [{"id":"5","value":"55555","text":"xxxxxx"}]]]
```

I want it really to be:

```
[{"id":"3","value":"33333","text":"Bbbbb"},
 {"id":"3","value":"33333","text":"Bbbbb"},
 {"id":"5","value":"55555","text":"xxxxxx"}]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I struggled with this for over a day now :)

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Display() {
        jar = new CookieJar({
            expires: 3600,   // seconds
            path: '/'
        });

        var itemArray = jar.get("Items");
        if (itemArray) {
            tmpDiv.innerHTML += itemArray.toJSONString() + '<br/>';

            for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
                tmpDiv.innerHTML += itemArray[i].item[0].value + '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }

    function ClickButton(id, value, text) {
        jar = new CookieJar({
            expires: 3600,   // seconds
            path: '/'
        });

        var tmpA = jar.get("Items");
        var items = new Array;

        items.push({ "id": id, "value": value, "text": text });

        // If any existing values in the cookie, load and add to Array
        if (tmpA != null)
            items.push(tmpA);

        tmpDiv.innerHTML += items.toJSONString() + "<br/>";
        jar.put("Items", items);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your button is clicked, you're creating a new array called `items`, then adding the old array called `tmpA` to it.  Then, you stash `items`, which now has a new child array inside it (representing the previous value, which itself was an array).

Instead of:

```
    if (tmpA != null)
        items.push(tmpA);
```

You should have:

```
    if (tmpA != null)
        items = items.concat(tmpA); // this will merge the two arrays
```

Comment: I love it!! Works perfect. I have completely misunderstood the push function as I thought it was the way to add items to an array.

Comment: It is quite literally the way to add items to an array -- and if those items are arrays themselves, you'll end up with nested arrays :)